# At what angle do tangents of $3x^2-6x+2y^2-3=0$ intersect in $T(1,3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, derivatives

We have curve: $$3x^2-6x+2y^2-3=0$$

And two tangents of that curve which both pass through: $$T(1,3)$$

What is the angle they intersect at?

I got this:

$t_1.....y=a_1x+b_1$
$t_2.....y=a_2x+b_2$

$3=a_1+b_1$
$3=a_2+b_2$

$6x-6+4yy'=0$ 
$y'=\frac{-6x+6}{4y}$

I am not sure where to go from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting first the equations of the tangent lines, I would set first the tangent points.

Let $(p,q),(r,s)$ be the tangent points.

Since 
$$3x^2-6x+2y^2-3=0\implies 2yy'=-3x+3$$
the two tangent lines are given by
$$(y-q)(2q)=(-3p+3)(x-p)$$
$$(y-s)(2s)=(-3r+3)(x-r)$$
Since these pass through $T$, we get
$$(3-q)(2q)=(-3p+3)(1-p)\iff 3p^2-6p+2q^2=6q-3=3$$$$\implies q=1,3p^2-6p-1=0$$
$$(3-s)(2s)=(-3r+3)(1-r)\iff 3r^2-6r+2s^2=6s-3$$$$\implies s=1,3r^2-6r-1=0$$

So, $$q=s=1,\quad p,r=\frac{3\pm 2\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Therefore, we have two tangent lines :
$$\sqrt 3\ x+y=1+\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{3}\sqrt 3$$
$$-\sqrt 3\ x+y=1-\frac{3-2\sqrt{3}}{3}\sqrt 3$$
Now, if we let $\theta$ be the angle between the two lines, then
$$\cos\theta=\frac{|\sqrt 3\times (-\sqrt 3)+1\times 1|}{\sqrt{(\sqrt 3)^2+1^2}\sqrt{(-\sqrt 3)^2+1^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\implies \theta=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

Comment: Le God of math.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Notice that the curve is an ellipse:

$$ 3x^2-6x+2y^2-3= \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{3} - 1 =0 $$

This suggests the parameterization:

$$\textbf{x}_t = (1+\sqrt2\cos(t), \sqrt3\sin(t)) $$

for a general point on the ellipse. The tangent vector is given by differentiating:

$$\textbf{x}^{'}_t = (-\sqrt2\sin(t), \sqrt3\cos(t)) $$

Now the general equation for a tangent line is:

$$ \textbf{x}- \textbf{x}_t=\lambda \textbf{x}^{'}_t$$

since the point $\textbf{p} = (1,3)$ satisfies this, we get:

$$ (-\sqrt2\cos(t), 3-\sqrt3\sin(t)) = (-\lambda\sqrt2\sin(t), \lambda \sqrt3\cos(t)) $$

Equate the two components separately (and noticing that $\sin(t)=0$ is not a solution), we get a linear equation in $\sin(t)$

$\sin(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

$\cos(t)=\frac{\pm \sqrt 2}{\sqrt3}$

$\lambda=\pm \sqrt 2$

Thus the two tangent vectors (let's call them $\textbf{x}^{'}_{t1} $ and $\textbf{x}^{'}_{t2} $ are $ (\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt3},2)$.

Calculate $$ \cos \theta = \frac{\textbf{x}^{'}_{t1} \cdot \textbf{x}^{'}_{t1}}{|\textbf{x}^{'}_{t1}||\textbf{x}^{'}_{t2}|} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the eqation of a tangent be $y=mx+c$ and let us find the intersection with $3x^2-6x+2y^2-3=0$

$3x^2-6x+2(mx+c)^2-3=0\iff(3+2m^2)x^2+2x(2mc-3)+2c^2-3=0$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $x$ each value of $x$ represents the abscissa of intersection.  For
 tangency, both root should be same, i.e., the discriminant must be zero

$4(9+4m^2c^2-12mc)=4(3+2m^2)(2c^2-3)$
$\iff6(m^2-c^2-2mc+3)=0\ \ \ \ \  (1)$

Now as the s the tangent passes through $(1,3);3=m\cdot1+3\iff c=3-m$

Put this value in $(1)$ to find $m^2-3=0$

We need $\arctan\left|\dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$

Answer (score 0):

Applying derivative   $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{3(1-x)}{2y}$$

Like  foofaafuu,    $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}_{\text{ at} x=1+\sqrt2\cos t,y=\sqrt3\sin t}=\dfrac{3(1-x)}{2y}=-\sqrt{\dfrac32}\cot t$$

So, the equation of the tangent  $$3x(\sqrt2\cos t)+2y(\sqrt3\sin t)-3(2+2\cos t)=0$$

As it passes through  $(1,3)$

$3\cdot1(\sqrt2\cos t)+2\cdot(\sqrt3\sin t)-3(2+2\cos t)=0\implies\sin t=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$

$\implies\cot t=\pm\dfrac1{\csc^2t-1}=\pm\sqrt2$

So, the gradients $(m_1,m_2)$ of the tangents are $$-\sqrt{\dfrac32}\cot t=\mp\sqrt3$$

We need $\arctan\left|\dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$